# Integrating cassandra and shark

Tags: cassandra, hive, apache-spark, shark-sql

I am trying to get shark working on Cassandra, so i pull the data from Cassandra into shark and run queries. I used CASH open source storage handler, it seems to work when i run shark locally but when in distributes mode looks like spark slaves don't send output back to master (i cannot see output at shark shell).

Comment: did you resolve it ? How does your configuration looks like ?

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is available in new DataStax Enterprise 4.5. It fully integrates Cassandra with Spark and Shark. You may take a look if you want, but this is not an open-source.